# Header overlapping body content

Tags: html, css, header

So I'm working on a layout and have completed the header. When I started working on the body content, I kept running into the issue where the header would overlap the body unless I set a top margin of the body wrapper to something huge (300+px) even then it can overlap when the screen is small. I think I have screwed up the positioning somewhere but I can't seem to figure out how to overcome this.

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="pageWrapper">
<div id="mainHeader">
<div id="mainNav">
<div id="navContent">
<div class="mainLogo"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img class="navIcons" src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/dashboard.png" />Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img class="navIcons" src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/patient.png" />Patients</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img class="navIcons" src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/devices.png" />Devices</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img class="navIcons" src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/account.png" />Account</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img class="navIcons" src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/support.png" />Support</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="lvpLogo"><strong>LifeView</strong> Portal</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="subNav">
<span class="loginName">Doctor Brian Town</span>
</div>
</div>
<div id="bodWrap">
<div class="statWrap"><div class="titleWrap"><span>Chronic Disease Summary</span></div>
<img src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/support.png" /><img src="img/icons/account.png" /><img src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/devices.png" /><img src="http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/icons/patient.png" />
</div>
<div class="statWrap"><div class="titleWrap"><span>Vital Summary</span></div>

</div>
<div class="statWrap"><div class="titleWrap"><span>Alerts</span></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}
.pageWrapper {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
.mainLogo {
background:url(http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/home_02.png) no-repeat left;
height: 77px;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 26px;
margin-right: 30px;
float: left;
}
#mainHeader {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px;
}
#mainNav {
/*height: 109px;*/
width: 100%;
float: left;
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #FFFFFF;
/*background:url(http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/img/home_01.jpg) repeat-x scroll top;*/
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0e448e 0%, #2b2c2e 100%);
/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0e448e 0%, #2b2c2e 100%);
/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0e448e 0%, #2b2c2e 100%);
/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0e448e), color-stop(1, #2b2c2e));
/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0e448e 0%, #2b2c2e 100%);
/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0e448e 0%, #2b2c2e 100%);
}
#navContent {
padding-top: 20px;
}
#mainNav #navContent ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; 
}
#mainNav #navContent li {
float: left; 
}
#mainNav #navContent li a {
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;   
}
#mainNav #navContent li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
#mainNav #navContent li a:hover {
color: #23afff;
}
#mainNav #navContent h1 {
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.lvpLogo {
margin: auto auto auto auto;
display: inline-block;
word-spacing: 20px;
vertical-align: top;
float: right;
padding-right: 80px;
}
.lvpLogo strong {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.navIcons {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 1px;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
}
#subNav {
overflow: hidden;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #000000;
/* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #cccccc 100%);
/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #cccccc 100%);
/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #cccccc 100%);
/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #cccccc));
/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #cccccc 100%);
/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #cccccc 100%);
}
.loginName {
float: right;
margin-right: 120px;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 40px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#bodWrap {
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #000000;
}
.statWrap {
margin: 10px auto auto auto;
border: 2px solid #000;
border-radius: 19px;
width: 80%;
background-color: #eee;
}
.titleWrap {
postion: absolute;
background-color: #00639c;
top: 0;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
}
.titleWrap span {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
margin: auto auto auto 33px;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Artsen/tKdqh/
Test Environment:
http://lifeview.michiganweb.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated your jsfiddle, please see here: [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/tKdqh/1/)

Basically I changed the `position:absolute;` to a `position:relative;` for the mainHeader div

Comment: WOW that was so fast. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` only from #mainHeader css

**DEMO HERE**

http://jsfiddle.net/tKdqh/2/

Comment: I just made that change and sadly it makes it so the header doesn't stretch 100% is there a way to accomplish both?

Comment: i am using CHROME and it seems to streched 100% :) Are you talking about 2 to 3px spacing at the start and end of the header?

Comment: Hmm I'm checking it out in firefox currently and it looks like this http://puu.sh/2yHLZ

Update just checked it out in chrome and it looks the same, hmm

Comment: Jesus!!! My Firefox is 20.0.1 and it shows fully stretched.. why don't you try after clearing browser's cache and history

Comment: Weird, I'm using the same version of firefox and I just cleared out my cache and flushed my dns for good measure too. I know I have run into similar issues before, it wouldn't want to stretch for me unless I made it position absolute, however if I do that my body content will be overlapped.

Comment: I fixed the problem! It turns out the default value for margin: on the body was around 8px, I just needed to set that to 0 and it fixed everything. Thank you!